# vue-router route with params not working on page reload

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am using vue-router on my project.

I am able to navigate to my named routes perfectly fine. My only problem is when I use a named route which expects a parameter, it does not load when I refresh the page.

here is my route:

```js
'/example/:username': {
    name: 'example-profile',
    title: 'Example Profile',
    component: ExampleComponent
}
```

this is how I am using the `vue-router` `route`:

```html
<a v-link="{ name: 'example-profile', params: { username: raaaaf } }">
    Example Link
</a>
```

When I select `Example Link` I get `mydomain.com/example/raaaaf`.

On first load, it renders the correct template, but when I refresh or manually entered the link on the address bar, I am redirected to my `Page Not Found` page and the method called when the page is created is not triggered.

This is what I have on my `ExampleComponent`:

```html
    <template>
    <div class="small-12 left">
        <side-bar></side-bar>
        <div class="store-right">
            <store-details></store-details>
            <store-menu></store-menu>
            <store-listings></store-listings>
        </div>
    </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
        export default {
            data() {
                return {
                    username: null,
                    user: null,
                }
            },
    
            created() {
                this.getUser()
            },
    
            methods: {
                getUser() {
                    console.log(this.$route.params);
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to configure your server properly. Your server is essetially looking for an index file in a `/example/raaaaf` directory. I'd read through this page carefully: http://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html

Answer (score 8):

I don't know if anyone else if facing the same issue, but I was having a problem getting route params on refresh. The route parameter I was trying to get was an ID number and I use that ID to fetch data and populate the page. I found (through many console logs) when I refreshed, the number was turning into a string and thats why the page was not working. I sorted it out but casting the ID to number before using it:

```
Number($route.params.id)
```

Comment: This bit me not too long ago! A good place to do this is in https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#function-mode if anyone is curious.