# Losing router.params on page refresh

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm encountering an issue with vue-router.
I got a list of posts in the homepage. When I click on one of them, it redirects to the post page such as :

`<router-link :to="{ name: 'article', params: {id: article.id, slug: article.slug } }"></router-link>`

Everything is working perfectly, I can retrieve the data of the correct article using `this.$route.params.id` in a getter.

**My issue :** When I reload on an article page, `this.$route.params.id` is undefined, which causes the entire application to crash.

How can I save the `router.params` despite a page reload ?

Comment: What is your route definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What backend are you using? You need to [enable `history mode` on your router](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html), as well as make some additional configuration changes on your backend web server. [Please refer to this link for the additional server side configuration changes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations) you will need to make for this to work properly.

Also, [please make note of this 404 caveat](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#caveat) when using `history mode`..

***Edit:*** you could try [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39950582/vue-router-route-with-params-not-working-on-page-reload) since the ID remains persistent in the URL: **Look for the solution from *MIKE AXLE***

> I don't know if anyone else if facing the same issue, but I was having a problem getting route params on refresh. The route parameter I was trying to get was an ID number and I use that ID to fetch data and populate the page. I found (through many console logs) when I refreshed, the number was turning into a string and thats why the page was not working. I sorted it out but casting the ID to number before using it:
>
> Number($route.params.id)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm using Laravel. Apache mod_rewrite is already set up, as well as the 404 page. I still have the route and the URL is ok but component isn't loading because i use `this.$route.params.id` in it, which is undefined when I reload

Comment: Does the ID persist in the URL or does it get removed on refresh as well?

Comment: It persists on the URL

Comment: It may be a long shot, but you could [try this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39950582/vue-router-route-with-params-not-working-on-page-reload) I have updated my answer with the possible solution (not the one marked as accepted, the one below it)

Comment: Indeed that was it! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `query` instead of params

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'article', query: {id: article.id, slug: article.slug } }"></router-link>
```

and to get value on redirecting page

```
this.$route.query
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what is your route definition, the problem can be that only one of the params presented in the route URL (e.g. `/article/:slug`).

When you invoke a route (by clicking on `router-link` or calling `router.push`), you passing both params directly and they persist in the memory. That's why both are accessible.
But when you reload the page - everything that Vue can do is to parse your URL.
Means only one param parsed because only one param is present.

As a solution you can:

- use both params in the route URL (e.g. `/article/:id/:slug`);
- or use one param and call your API to retrieve remaining information (e.g. get `id` by slug if your route is `/article/:slug`).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue pass the url in router

```
/article/:id/:slug
```

you will not loose your params after resfresh because whenrefreshng vue will take only data from url and forget if you passed params

Answer (score 1):

You should route like this:

```
{
      path: '/article/:id/:slug',
      name: 'article', 
}
```

In your view when routing do it like this:

```
this.$router.push({ name: 'article', params: { id: articleID, slug: articleSlug}});
```

You're welcome!